# Add text filter box to R shiny render table

Tags: r, filter, datatable, shiny

I have created the following app using R shiny and canada.cities dataset

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("canada.cities"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    canada.cities[,c(1,2)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to a set of filter boxes beneath each column such that i can filter each column in the output table by an entry in that column.It should be like a searchbox and filter based on the unique entries for each column. For example countries.etc column should be filtered on basis of BC, AB, QC etc. How do I accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the answer Sir

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
h2("canada.cities"),
DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
(datatable(canada.cities[,c(1,2)],filter = 'top'))
  })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```